# Cannot compile exqlite on Windows

Tags: sqlite, elixir

### Background

I am trying to run this Elixir desktop app in my Windows VM:
https://github.com/elixir-desktop/desktop-example-app

I have installed Erlang OTP 24.X manually in my windows:
https://erlang.org/download/otp_win64_24.1.4.exe

And I have installed Elixir via the official website after, and have it configured to use the Erlang/OTP version I mentioned before:
https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#windows

### Problem

So, I cloned the project and run `mix deps.get` as usual.
After that I ran `mix deps.compile` and I got an error:

```
λ mix deps.compile
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling dbus
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling ranch
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling telemetry
==> exqlite
could not compile dependency :exqlite, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile exqlite", update it with "mix deps.update exqlite" or clean it with "mix deps.clean exqlite"
** (Mix) "nmake" not found in the path. If you have set the MAKE environment variable,
please make sure it is correct.
```

This means I have an issue with a dependency:

```
λ mix deps.compile exqlite
==> exqlite
could not compile dependency :exqlite, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile exqlite", update it with "mix deps.update exqlite" or clean it with "mix deps.clean exqlite"
** (Mix) "nmake" not found in the path. If you have set the MAKE environment variable,
please make sure it is correct.
```

### What I tried

So, I am guessing my sqlite installation on my windows is not well done. I have installed sqlite in windows by following this tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm

Which boils down to:

1. Go to [SQLite download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and download precompiled binaries from Windows section.
2. Download `sqlite-shell-win32-*.zip` and `sqlite-dll-win32-*.zip` zipped files.
3. − Create a folder `C:\>sqlite` and unzip above two zipped files in this folder, which will give you `sqlite3.def`, `sqlite3.dll` and `sqlite3.exe` files.
4. − Add `C:\>sqlite` in your PATH environment variable and finally go to the command prompt and issue sqlite3 command, which should work.

And in fact when I type `sqlite3` in my prompt, it does work.

However I understand I am still missing some step, but I can't figure out what.

### Question

What am I missing to compile the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my issue is because `exqlite` uses a NIF. This means I needed to do an extra setup step for windows, where I install the `cpp` tools and then compile the `exqlite` using this prompt:

- cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

The full guide can be seen here:
https://hexdocs.pm/exqlite/windows.html

More information on the official forum:

- https://elixirforum.com/t/cannot-compile-exqlite-on-windows/43693/2?u=fl4m3ph03n1x